# How to know and remove unused custom modules / extensions in Magento 1.x and Magento 2.x?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2.3, extensions, third-party-module

I have two different stores of `Magento 1.9` and `Magento 2.3`. I need to know details of unused custom extensions and third party modules of my stores which are enable but not used for long time, so that I can disable/remove it. Is there any method or way to do that in Magento ...?

Comment: Please elaborate cuuz you caz know the status of disabled extension by `php bin/magento module:status`

Comment: Hii @PartabSaifuddinZakir, Thanks for your reply. Yes we can know the status of the module in both Magento 1.x and 2.x. But I need to know the extensions which are enabled and were used previously, but they are not used now for a long time ...

Comment: As far as I know you have to check the code of your custom or third party modules to see what task they're performing...

Comment: Yes, I know the use of each custom extensions and third party modules, but how could I know that the particular task which is done by that extension/module; is not performed since long time?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't know that...

Comment: It's okay brother @PartabSaifuddinZakir , No problem... I am digging Magento to get the solution for it. Once I will get a proper solution for it, then will let you know. Thanks for spending your time...

Answer (score 0):

This is only half the answer, but your question is pretty broad, so I'm doing my best...

The short answer is that there really isn't a universal way to do this because it will depend on your extension.

The long answer is that you could either disable the extension to see if it causes problems or find ways of tracking usage.  You could try to log an entry every time an extension is loaded, but that will depend on the extension and what it is used for.

I would recommend looking for a `_construct()` or `__construct` (Note the additional '_') function in one of the `Block`, `Model` or `controllers` folders, then use [Mage::log()](http://www.blogtreat.com/create-custom-log-magelog-magento/) to see when it is loaded.  For example:

In a file like `<magento-root>/app/code/<community-OR-local>/Custom/Extension/Block/Custom.php`, add the beginning of the file would look something like this:

```
<?php
class Custom_Extension_Block_Custom extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

  protected function _construct() {

    // THIS IS THE LINE YOU WOULD ADD
    Mage::log('Custom_Extension_Block_Custom->_construct() called from the following url:   '.Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl());

    parent::_construct();

    $this->setSomeBlockData('some block data');
  }

    //  ... more code before file ends
}
```

This will tell you when and where it the block is being created, which would work similarly for Models and controllers.

It is worth noting that some extensions will automatically be used when certain pages are loaded, just because the extension is enabled and it automatically overrides default template/model/other files.  Also, this is for Magento 1, but I am sure you could find similar ways to track Magento 2 extensions.